# Finding the limit of a function and its reciprocal

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, singularity

I would like to compute

$$\displaystyle\lim_{z \to 0} f(z) = \displaystyle\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z \cos z - \sin z}{\frac{1}{3}\cos^3z-\cos z + \frac{2}{3}}$$

and also

$$\displaystyle\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1}{f(z)} = \frac{\frac{1}{3}\cos^3z-\cos z + \frac{2}{3}}{z \cos z - \sin z}$$

I am struggling to calculate either of these. Is it as simple as recursively applying L'Hospital's rule since we obtain indeterminate forms in both?

I've also tried multiplying each by $\frac{ \cos z}{ \cos z}$ and $\frac{ \sin z}{ \sin z}$, but end up with the same indeterminate form every time. Any thoughts on computing these limits? I have graphed both of these and I know that $z=0$ is a pole of $f$ since $f(z) \to \infty$ as $z \to 0$and $\frac{1}{f(z)} \to 0$ as $z \to 0$. But I am struggling to show each of these things.

Comment: Hint: step 1, L'Hopital; step 2, algebraic simplification; step 3, two well known limits.

Comment: @David If step 1 is L'Hospital, then eventually we get a finite answer, don't we - and thus we wouldn't need the other steps? Because either L'Hospital gives us a definite answer or it fails to work, right? Unless we apply L'Hospital some fixed number of times and then the algebraic simplification follows. Even then, how would I know how many times do we apply the rule before doing algebra?

Comment: Use Taylor expansion for numerator and denominator and then long division

Comment: @DavidC.Huang Maybe it was not clear but my previous comment is about this problem.  I am certainly not saying that every problem can be solved in the same way.  I know that L'Hopital is only needed once in this problem because I tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$ \cos^3z-3\cos z +2=\cos^3z-\cos z -2\cos z+2=(1-\cos z)(\sin^2z +2)$$ Therefore $$f(z):={z\cos z -\sin z\over {1\over 3}\cos^3-\cos z+{2\over 3}} ={3\over \sin^2z+2} \, {z\cos z -\sin z\over 1-\cos z}$$
Next
$${z\cos z -\sin z\over 1-\cos z}=-z+{z-\sin z\over 1-\cos z}$$
Hence the limit in question is equal $${3\over 2}\, \lim_{z\to 0}{z-\sin z\over 1-\cos z}$$ We have
$${z-\sin z\over 1-\cos z}={z-\sin z\over z^3}{z^2\over 1-\cos z}\,z$$
As
$$z-\sin z={z^3\over 6} +o(z^3),\qquad 1-\cos z={z^2\over 2}+o(z^3),\quad{\rm when}\ z\to 0$$ we get
$$\lim_{z\to 0}{z-\sin z\over z^3}{z^2\over 1-\cos z}\,z={1\over 6}\cdot 2\cdot 0=0$$
Summarizing $\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)=0$ and the limit of ${1\over f(z)}$ at $z=0$ does not exist.

Comment: But $f(z)$ has a simple pole at $z=0$, so $f$ cannot have a limit for $z=0$

Comment: It is not a pole, but a removable singularity. In the last limit the point $0$ is the root of order $2$ of the denominator and of order $3$ of the numerator. Therefore the limit is equal $0.$ Shall I extend the answer ?

Comment: Sure, I think that would help